# Angular6: How to set and pass params with HttpParams in a single line?

Tags: angular, http, angular5, angular6

Currently, I am doing something like this... 
`let params = new HttpParams().set('search', search);
return this.http.get('/api/object/', {params});` 
Is there a way I could do it in one line instead of two? 
Something like (This doesn't work, gives type error): 
`return this.http.get('/api/object/', {new HttpParams().set('search', search)});`

Reference: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE:**

Doing

```
return this.http.get('/api/object/', {params});
```

Created an `options` object with key `params` and value hold by the `params` variable. It's basically a short-hand syntax for:

```
return this.http.get('/api/object/', { params: params });
```

And it's taken care of by ES6. You can essentially use it when the name of the `key` and the variable containing the `value` of that key are the same.(both are `params` in the first case)

But doing what you're doing in the next piece of code won't do that implicitly. So you'll have to explicitly mention the name of the key(i.e. `params`) in the `options` object that you're passing as the second argument to `get`

**FIX:**

Add the key name as `params` in the Object that you're passing as the second argument to `get`

```
return this.http.get('/api/object/', { params: new HttpParams().set('search', search) });
```

Comment: @Nirzari, please consider marking one of the answers as a solution to close the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`{ params }` is a shortcut for `{ params: params }`. It only works because you have defined a local variable named `params` before that.

All you need is

```
return this.http.get('/api/object/', {params: new HttpParams().set('search', search)});
```

or simply

```
return this.http.get('/api/object/', { params: { search: search} });
```

or, using the same shortcut as for params:

```
return this.http.get('/api/object/', { params: { search } });
```